# Evans PDEs Appendix 4 pg. 628, how to compute $dS$ in Spherical coordinates conversion?

Tags: calculus

He gives us a method to compute integrals in spherical coordinates in $n$ dimensions, via the conversion

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f dx = \int_0^\infty \left(\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)} f dS\right) dr
$$

for any selected point $x_0$.

It seems silly to ask, but I am confused as to what the interior integral means. There is no explanation as to how such an integral is computed. I vaguely remember something of the sort from my multivariable calculus courses, years ago, but the details are foggy and looking at resources online is confusing me more because examples online always give a particular surface S and only then write dS.

What is meant here?

Comment: The particular surface here is, as stated, the boundary of the ball $B(x_0,r)\,.$

Comment: But what is the actual rigorous definition of the integral over the ball? And then, how are these integrals generally computed?

Comment: [Surface integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral).

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why that got so muddled in my head.

Comment: No worries. If you practice lots of concrete examples (not that difficult imo) you can become a star on MSE.